# Why do humans masturbate?

Tags: human-biology, neurophysiology, sex, human-physiology

Why does masturbating seem to be like an addiction?

What controls or initiates the urge to masturbate?

Is it good or bad or both and why is it so? I have heard guys who say that the do it regularly. Also there is a relaxing feeling; what generates that?

Comment: You probably mean *masturbate* instead of *masterbate*. I edited it. I also remove the triple interrogation mark, remove the spaces around interrogation marks and points and not use both interrogation mark and point.

Comment: The question is more on-topic on [Health.SE](http://health.stackexchange.com/). But before you ask your question over there, note that if you google your questions you will find millions of hits because you are very clearly not the first one to ask this kind of question.

Comment: I searched on google but most of time i get only one answer that it is good...

Comment: Maybe you should using the word *masturbate* instead of *masterbate* and try with a more accurate question. There is definitely loads of information. Way more than what you could read. For example, in your question you do not specify whether you are interested in physical or mental health. In its current form, I am voting to close the question as too broad.

Comment: I think it's on topic, there are Evolutionary hypotheses for masturbation and studies of how it affects sperm and ejaculate quality, and how that in turn can affect fitness

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One word.

## DOPAMINE

See this article on [Reward System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reward_system) and this one on [Dopamine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dopamine) Those basically answer your question as to addiction, urge, and feelings of relaxation.

There is absolutely nothing wrong with masturbation, so long as you realize that it is a healthy expression of one's sexuality, that is observed, quite frequently, in our nearest relative, the [Bonobo](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=5SUFxfft7zMC&oi=fnd&pg=PA37&dq=bonobo+masturbation&ots=brbeiBN4nz&sig=4LZWSlORnPC-kTgyva6yghp3-fE#v=onepage&q=bonobo%20masturbation&f=false). There is no shortage of the study of primate masturbatory practices in the literature, and one could make a career out of its scientific study and analysis, so if you are interested in learning more, conducting a Google Scholar search on Primate Masturbation should give you literally years worth of reading material.

As for an actual addiction, it would only develop into a pathology if it became disruptive to one's life and was pursued at the exclusion of other basic activities.

Comment: Masturbating can yield to a strong addiction that can be bad for health just because it prevents one to have a normal social life. Also some are masturbating so much that they can injure themselves. So it is not as easy as to just say `There is absolutely nothing wrong with masturbation`.

Comment: @Remi.b I agree that that statement should be qualified, but I think AMR was speaking to religious/cultural conservatism that frowns upon masturbation as some sort of "sin" or social ill.

Comment: @Remi.b If you notice I had qualified my statement as to when it can become pathological. However, as with alcohol, or shopping, or food, or sex, or gambling, most can maintain a healthy balance and control without developing an addiction to the stimulus.

Comment: @Remi.b Scientific literature would contradict your impression. http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1300/J056v14n02_02 and http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10508-010-9722-0 as examples.

Comment: Oh... I guess I missed your last sentence. Sorry about that. +1

Comment: @MattDMo More cultural than religious. Just as antivaccine ignores the scientific data to support an agenda, so to do those spreading superstition when it comes to sexual development. The scientific reality is far different from Remi.b. Yes, there will be a few that can become addicted, as it is linked into the neurological reward system, but for most it is a healthy part of development and coming to terms with their sexuality. Also physical injury is a fallacy, perpetuated with the same agenda looking to suppress the behavior.

Comment: @AMR I agree. I was raised in a fairly conservative religious environment, which is why I read religion into your statement.

Comment: @MattDMo, Don't need to be conservatively religious to have been sold an unhealthy view of normal sexual development. Just think of Seinfeld's Master of My Domain episode.